# How to install Imap on Amazon Linux with PHP 7.2.13

Tags: amazon-ec2, php-7.2, amazon-linux, php-imap

I am setting up a new instance and trying to install php-imap on it with no luck.

I am using: `sudo yum install php-imap`

And getting the following output:

`Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                | 2.1 kB     00:00

amzn-updates                                             | 2.5 kB     00:00

Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-imap.x86_64 0:5.3.29-1.8.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.29-1.8.amzn1 for package: php-imap-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.29-1.8.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php72-common-7.2.13-1.7.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.22-1.98
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php72-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`

Anyone have been able to install it on Amazon Linux (free tier) with Php version 7.2.13?

Comment: I managed to install it using ´sudo yum install php72-imap´